# How can I remove the embedded preview in an EPS file without destroying all metadata?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, file-metadata

I have several EPS files data exported from Adobe Illustrator, which apparently embeds a TIFF preview so that the EPS file is previewable.

This is undesired, because I use these files in XeLaTeX, which complains with

> ```
> Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 198 replaced by U+FFFD
> ```

This is caused by the binary data in the TIFF preview. I'd like to safely remove this preview. I do not have access to Adobe Illustrator. I would like to use tools available on Unix/Linux.

## `exiftool` output

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.15
File Name                       : ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 492 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:05:13 15:24:17+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:05:13 15:24:17+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2016:05:13 15:24:17+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : EPS
File Type Extension             : eps
MIME Type                       : application/postscript
TIFF Preview                    : (Binary data 123976 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Subfile Type                    : Full-resolution Image
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Compression                     : Uncompressed
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB Palette
Samples Per Pixel               : 2
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Strip Offsets                   : 379936
Strip Byte Counts               : 115542
Color Map                       : (Binary data 1536 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Extra Samples                   : Associated Alpha
Clipping Path Name              : Path
Creator                         : Adobe Illustrator(R) 8.0
For                             : Some cool company GmbH
Title                           : ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
Create Date                     : 4/18/2007 10:49 AM
Bounding Box                    : 100 376 542 508
Version                         : 1.2 0
Copyright                       : (C) 1987-1996 Adobe Systems Incorporated All Rights Reserved
Image Height                    : 132
Image Width                     : 442
Image Size                      : 442x132
Megapixels                      : 0.058
```

Important line being:

> ```
> TIFF Preview                    : (Binary data 123976 bytes, use -b option to extract)
> ```

I would like to safely remove this from the file, while maintaining other metadata.

## Nuke metadata with imagemagick

The `-strip` parameter in imagemagick works, but it removes all metadata. This is not ideal.

```
find -iname '*.eps' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file convert -strip file file
```

## Precise Attempts with `exiftool`

### Attempt 1

```
exiftool -TIFFPreview:all= ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
```

yields

```
Warning: Sorry, Not a deletable group: TIFFPreview
Nothing to do.
```

### Attempt 2

```
exiftool -ThumbnailImage= -PreviewImage= ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
Warning: [minor] Entries in IFD0 were out of sequence. Fixed. - ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
```

yields

```
Warning: [minor] Entries in IFD0 were out of sequence. Fixed. - ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps
    0 image files updated
    1 image files unchanged
```

Comment: Try the `-P` option of ps2eps or delete the lines `%%BeginPreview:` and `%%EndPreview` and everything between manually.

Comment: @jofel I do not see `%%BeginPreview`. I do have a `AI7_Thumbnail: 128 40 8`  followed by `%%BeginData` and `%%EndData`. I do not have `ps2eps` currently installed. I tried earlier but it took so long and I needed my machine to do some work, so I cancelled the install. I can try it out later. I was hoping to achieve something with imagemagick or exiftool.

Comment: @jofel Unfortunately, although `ps2eps -P` works, it also deletes the EXIF data and Photoshop data :/ ALMOST there! I could even live with this as an answer. I would like to just remove the preview though. Checked with `exiftool -a -G -s ce_mark_with_cert_number.eps.eps` (default output of `ps2eps`)

Comment: @jofel Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it so we can close this up.